# Trouble with foreign key and belongsTo methods

Tags: mysql, sequelize.js

I'm making a fake online banking website. Having trouble with a certain part where I'm trying to make it so every user can have many accounts using the belongsTo method. I was the accounts table to hold the users foreign id.

Here's the Users model

```
module.exports = function (sequelize, DataTypes) {
    var User = sequelize.define("User", {

        firstName: {type:DataTypes.STRING, allowNull:false},
        lastName: {type:DataTypes.STRING, allowNull:false},
        addressLine1: {type:DataTypes.STRING, allowNull:false},
        addressLine2: {type:DataTypes.STRING, defaultValue: "Null"}, 
        city: {type:DataTypes.STRING, allowNull:false},
        state: {type:DataTypes.STRING, allowNull:false},
        zip: {type:DataTypes.INTEGER, allowNull:false},
        SSN:{type:DataTypes.STRING, allowNull: false},
        DOB: {type:DataTypes.STRING, allowNull:false},
        email: {type:DataTypes.STRING, allowNull:false},
        username: {type:DataTypes.STRING, allowNull:false},
        // acctNoCHK: {type:DataTypes.INTEGER, unique:true},
        // acctNoSAV: {type:DataTypes.INTEGER, unique:true}
    });

    User.associate = function (models) {
        User.hasMany(models.Account, {
            onDelete: "cascade"
        });
    };

    return User;
};
```

Here's the account model

```
module.exports = function(sequelize, DataTypes) {
  var Account = sequelize.define("Account", {
    type: {type:DataTypes.STRING, allowNull:false},
    balance: {type:DataTypes.STRING, allowNull:false},
    isOpen: {type:DataTypes.BOOLEAN, allowNull:false}
  });

  Account.associate = function(models) {
    Account.belongsTo(models.User, {
      foreignKey: "UserId", targetKey: "id"
    });
  };

  return Account;
};
```

what exactly am I doing wrong??? The UserId column in accounts always comes out as Null. Thank you for any help!

Comment: Can you please show how are you saving the data on Accounts?

Comment: I'm sorry, what exactly do you mean by that?

Comment: You just says that `UserId` is always null, So I thinking that you are trying to save something on the `UserId` but on db is null. Or how do you think the association works? Because I don't  understand your question then. Try to explain yourself better.

Answer (score 0):

```
  var Account = sequelize.define("Account", {
    type: {type:DataTypes.STRING, allowNull:false},
    balance: {type:DataTypes.STRING, allowNull:false},
    isOpen: {type:DataTypes.BOOLEAN, allowNull:false},
    userId: {type: DataTypes.INTEGER } // need userId in Account
  });
```

```
const { id } = await Uesr.create({ ... });
await Account.create({ ...  , userId: id});// we need save userId
```